# Unsigned __int128 literal GCC

Tags: c, gcc, int128

I have a function `foo(unsigned __int128)`.
How can I pass a literal of type `unsigned __int128` to the function?
My attempts:

```
   foo(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF23FFFFF); //Truncated (expected)
   foo(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF01FFFu); //Truncated (expected)
   foo(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF23FFFFull); //Truncated
   foo((unsigned __int128)0xFF45FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFull); //Truncated
```

As you can see, all of them are truncated.
How can I signal GCC, that an literal is an `unsigned __int128`?

Edit:
The gcc manual says:

> There is no support in GCC for expressing an integer constant of type __int128 for targets with long long integer less than 128 bits wide

Does that mean, that I can't write literals of type (unsigned) __int128?

Are there alternatives?

Comment: One workaround is `((unsigned __int128)0xFFFFFull<<64 | 0xFFFFFFFFF23FFFFFull)`.

Comment: @yao99 `ll` not needed.  `((unsigned __int128)0xFFFFFu<<64 | 0xFFFFFFFFF23FFFFFu)` is suffcient.

Comment: @yao99 Or would memcpy work, too?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51538694/1918193 and several other duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html

> 6.9 128-bit Integers
>
> As an extension the integer scalar type __int128 is supported for targets which have an integer mode wide enough to hold 128 bits. Simply write __int128 for a signed 128-bit integer, or unsigned __int128 for an unsigned 128-bit integer. There is no support in GCC for expressing an integer constant of type __int128 for targets with long long integer less than 128 bits wide.

So, no, you cannot have a literal 128-bit constant

Comment: "for targets with long long integer less than 128 bits wide"